# Summing values from pandas dataframe columns depending on row index value

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a NxN dataframe. Each row corresponds to a certain url given as its index (without "http://"). Each also column represents url with boolean values indicating if this page (row index) links to that page (column name). The urls are the same in index and columns.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from pandas import DataFrame

In [3]:  df = DataFrame({'domain1.com/url1':[True,False,False,True,False],'domain2.com/url2':[False,True,False,True,True],'domain1.com/url3':[False,False,False,True,False],'domain3.com/url4':[False,True,False,True,False],'domain2.com/url5':[False,True,False,True,True]}, index=['domain1.com/url1','domain2.com/url2','domain1.com/url3','domain3.com/url4','domain2.com/url5'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
                 domain1.com/url1 domain1.com/url3 domain2.com/url2  \
domain1.com/url1             True            False            False   
domain2.com/url2            False            False             True   
domain1.com/url3            False            False            False   
domain3.com/url4             True             True             True   
domain2.com/url5            False            False             True   

                 domain2.com/url5 domain3.com/url4  
domain1.com/url1            False            False  
domain2.com/url2             True             True  
domain1.com/url3            False            False  
domain3.com/url4             True             True  
domain2.com/url5             True            False
```

Now I can, for instance, count incoming and outgoing links for each url:

```
In [5]: in_links_count = df.sum(axis=0)

In [6]: in_links_count
Out[6]: 
domain1.com/url1    2
domain1.com/url3    1
domain2.com/url2    3
domain2.com/url5    3
domain3.com/url4    2
dtype: int64

In [7]: out_links_count = df.sum(axis=1)

In [8]: out_links_count
Out[8]: 
domain1.com/url1    1
domain2.com/url2    3
domain1.com/url3    0
domain3.com/url4    5
domain2.com/url5    2
dtype: int64
```

So far so good. But what if I want to count incoming and outgoing links only for *other* domains? I guess I need to somehow filter out columns row-wise. I tried something like transposing dataframe (in order to exclude columns) and filtering, but failed:

```
In [9]: df_t = df.T

In [10]: df_t[ filter(lambda x: x.split('/')[0] != df_t.index.map(lambda x: x.split('/')[0]), list(df_t)) ].sum(axis=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-279439127551> in <module>()
----> 1 df_t[ filter(lambda x: x.split('/')[0] != df_t.index.map(lambda x: x.split('/')[0]), list(df_t)) ].sum(axis=0)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any ideas, guys?

UPD:

@piRSquared offered a solution that produces second dataframe  via hierarchical index (stack(), index.to_series(), difference between axis, "False" values for missing data - see below); this works fine with moderate-sized data. However, for a big NxN dataframe (1000x1000) this is sure an overkill. Could there be another way, perhaps taking advantage of in-place filtering/mapping?

Comment: But what if I want to count incoming and outgoing links only for other domains? - Can you brief this point

Comment: I mean links leading to domains that differ from a domain of a url being considered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not very pandas but still... one can iterate over elements

```
In [40]: def same_domain(url1, url2):
    return url1.split('/')[0] == url2.split('/')[0]


In [41]: def clear_inner_links(df):
for r in df.index:
    for c in df.columns:
        if(same_domain(r,c)):
            df.loc[r,c] = False
return df
```

then just

```
df1.sum(0)
df1.sum(1)
```

Benchmark:

```
In [35]: new_df.shape
Out[35]: (500, 500)

In [36]: %timeit clear_inner_links(new_df)
1 loop, best of 3: 956 ms per loop
```

More pandas way:

```
In [102]: def same_domain(url1, url2):
   .....:         return url1.split('/')[0] == url2.split('/')[0]
   .....: 

In [103]: def apply_criterion(s):
   .....:         s[s.index.map(lambda x: same_domain(x,s.name))] = False
   .....:     

In [104]: def clear_inner_links2(df):
   .....:         df.apply(apply_criterion, axis=0)
   .....:         return df
   .....: 

In [105]: new_df.shape
Out[105]: (500, 500)

In [106]: %timeit clear_inner_links2(new_df)
1 loop, best of 3: 929 ms per loop
```

This second solution shows better performance than first one (or piRSquared's one which is ~50 times slower) for 1000+ data frames.

Comment: That's exacrly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Create a series of index/column pairs.  Filter out the ones that are same domains and fill back in with `False`.  Then add the axis1 sum to the axis0 sum.

```
def domain(x):
    return x.str.extract(r'([^/]+)', expand=False)

dfi = df.stack().index.to_series().apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, ['u1', 'u2']))
keep = domain(dfi.u1) != domain(dfi.u2)
df1 = df.stack().ix[keep].unstack().fillna(False)

df1.sum(0) + df1.sum(1)

domain1.com/url1    1
domain1.com/url3    1
domain2.com/url2    2
domain2.com/url5    1
domain3.com/url4    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks for a nice and clear idea! what version of pandas are you using - i'm getting extract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand' and AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'extract' in 0.17

Comment: 0.18.1.  Just remove that argument.  I put it because I get a warning if I don't.  You don't need it at the moment.

Comment: tried it at home with a big df, unfortunately, stack().index.to_series() literally heats a pretty powerful notebook, maybe there are variants other than creating gigantic series in the middle of the process?